# Could not load UI satellite dll 'FileTracker32UI.dll'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I've run in to an issue where I can't build a freshly created C++/CLI Class Library project in Visual Studio:

[image]

Even though I haven't made any changes I get an error when I try to compile:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not load UI satellite dll 'FileTracker32UI.dll'.  Make
>   sure it exists in an LCID subdirectory of 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\'. TestProject c:\Users\abcde\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\FileTracker  1

I've created C++/CLI Class Library projects in the past on the same computer using Visual Studio 2015 without encountering this problem. Any idea what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this strange issue today without making any code change. I suspect it appeared due to overnight windows update. 
In my case , I copied the two files FileTracker32UI.dll and FileTracker64UI.dll

From
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\FileTracker\3082\
To
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\3082\

and it worked. My visual studio version is 
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

I am hoping the info helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exactly same problem, after some windows update by my IT. 
According to the information (https://forum.dlang.org/post/ezuohezwuzyitjdzpfdw@forum.dlang.org), I renamed the file "FileTrackerUI.dll" to "FileTracker32UI.dll" in the latest LCID folder (latest numbered folder in same location)

Then, it worked at my PC. 
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it didn't work for me. I ended up just installing VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a path issue. Using another directory (shorter path without special characters) solved the problem